# Bitul and gid hanashe

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bitul-batel-null, yoreh-deah, gid-hanashe

According to Halacha, can Gid Hanashe be nullified according to the laws of bitul (nullification of non kosher if it’s 1/60 or less in a meal)? Or is it similar to Chametz on Pesach which can’t be nullified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be nullified unless the (biblically) forbidden section remains intact. See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah [100:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.100.1?lang=bi):

> בריה דהיינו כגון נמלה או עוף טמא וגיד הנשה ואבר מן החי וביצה שיש בה
> אפרוח וכיוצא בהם אפי' באלף לא בטלה... הגה ועיקר גיד הנשה אינו אלא על
> הכף בלבד והוא כרוחב ד' אצבעות ואם הוא שלם מקרי בריה

Comment: The reason here is that a complete nerve is a *berya* (let's roughly translate as "organism"); that's completely different than Chametz on Pesach. If I know that one teaspoon of ground-up sciatic nerve fell into this giant pot of potato soup, the soup is kosher.

Comment: If it is intact and can be identified, it can be removed from the food, and the associated fats are batel b'shishim. 100:2 and [65:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.65.9&with=Commentary) are also relevant for a complete answer. | @Shalom The Taz cites the leniency of the Rashba that since we rule אין בגידין בנותן טעם, even a simple majority of permitted food is enough to nullify ground-up sciatic nerve (as opposed to the Shulchan Aruch who requires a 60:1 ratio to nullify it). The Taz indicates that we can rely on this leniency if we are uncertain about the proportions.

Comment: @Fred But if was intact and then broke down during cooking it's still a problem.

Comment: @shmosel In that case, the *gid* would be *batel b'shishim*, or, according to the Rashba, *batel b'rov*. See my previous comment.

Comment: Never mind, I see in 101:6 that it can become nullified when broken down.

Comment: Yes, that's why this answer is technically not wrong, but also misleading vis-a-vis the way the question was phrased.